# transfer knowledge learned from distributed source domains

Tags: tensorflow-federated

To resolve the problem of non-iid data in federated learning, I read a paper which add a new node with a different data domain and transfer knowledge from decentralized nodes. My question is what is the information transfered, is that updates or data ?

Answer (score 0):

In layman terms, non-idd means that not all class labels are distributed evenly between clients for training. For obvious reasons, in federated environment it is not feasible for every client to hold and train on idd data. With regards your specific query of how it works in the paper mentioned in your question, you may please share the link of the paper.